# Best way to form an aggregate dynamic mongo query either from UI or backend?

Tags: angular, mongodb, lambda, pymongo

I have a requirement to display a tabular format data after matching and grouping from mongodb, my grid can be drill down on n level after grid row selection, so my query would be dynamically grow as per user drilldown selection.

The data size will be very big, so i don't want to get that data at client side and do any kind of grouping and matching, so i am trying to create a dynamic aggregation mongo query each time and get the result from network.

I am able to achieve the result set using below aggregation query. when i will select a row to filter the data it will drilldown the result set and the query will also grow accordingly.
In the query the $match option will grow with **and** condition and the number of $group stages can also increase.

```
db.rule_execution_result.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            $and: [{
                    'topLevelFilter.id': {
                        $in: ['5fd1bd7868d7ac4e211a7642']
                    }
                },
                {
                    'ruleCategory': {
                        $nin: ['', null]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                ruleCategory: '$ruleCategory',
                topLevelFilter: '$topLevelFilter.id'
            },
            name: {
                $first: '$topLevelFilter.name'
            },
            type: {
                $first: '$topLevelFilter.type'
            },
            fail: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: ['$summaryStatus', 0]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            pass: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: ['$summaryStatus', 1]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            warn: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: ['$summaryStatus', 2]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id.ruleCategory',
            fail: {
                $sum: '$fail'
            },
            pass: {
                $sum: '$pass'
            },
            warn: {
                $sum: '$warn'
            },
            portfolio: {
                $push: {
                    id: '$_id.topLevelFilter',
                    name: '$name',
                    type: '$type',
                    fail: '$fail',
                    pass: '$pass',
                    warn: '$warn'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: 0,
            result: {
                $push: {
                    category: '$_id',
                    fail: '$fail',
                    pass: '$pass',
                    warn: '$warn',
                    portfolio: '$portfolio'
                }
            },
            fail: {
                $sum: '$fail'
            },
            pass: {
                $sum: '$pass'
            },
            warn: {
                $sum: '$warn'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            data: '$result',
            total: {
                fail: '$fail',
                pass: '$pass',
                warn: '$warn'
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

So here I have a few question where I am getting stuck to implement.

1. I will form the query dynamically to get the result, so there are two options: either I can create a query in my Angular application and I will send a JSON string in body and then I can execute it from my lembda function, or I can send some json structure to my lambda and I can make it in python.

   If I am going to send aggregation query from UI as a JSON string, then there are some concern from team related to security i.e, db injection kind of things. If i am going to send some json structure to my lambda function to create query, then i think i am going to implement one level of extra translation layer, that I want to avoid.

   So what will be the best approach to avoid injection stuff and achieve a good performance.

2. One more thing I am new to mongoDB, so if anyone can help me to optimise the query would be also a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The match does not require an `$and`. You can do it like this:

```
var matches = {};
matches['topLevelFilter.id'] = { $in: ['5fd1bd7868d7ac4e211a7642'] };
matches['ruleCategory'] = {  $nin: ['', null] };

var group = { _id: { ruleCategory: '$ruleCategory', topLevelFilter: '$topLevelFilter.id' } };
group.name = { $first: '$topLevelFilter.name' };

db.rule_execution_result.aggregate([
   { $match: matches },
   { $group: group }
])
```

You can easily add more fields to the stages. Or put all into one variable:

```
var pipeline = [];
pipeline.push({ $match: matches });
pipeline.push({ $group: group });
db.rule_execution_result.aggregate(pipeline);
```